# Kingston USB 3.0 Flash Drive write speed too slow

Tags: ssd, usb-flash-drive, dell-optiplex

I have a Dell Optiplex 990 mini tower and I bought a Digitus USB 3.0, 2-Port, PCI Express Add-On card.

I've connected it to the PCI-e 4x connector, I've installed the Renesas Usb 3.0 Host Controller Driver and everything works fine. But when I connect a USB 3.0 Flash Drive (Kingston DataTraveler 101 Generation 3 32GB) and I want to copy something, no matter how big it is, from my SSD to the flash drive, it copies only with max 15-16 MB/s, it behaves just like a usual USB 2.0 drive.

I don't know what to do in this case, I updated all the drivers for chipset. Please help.

Cheers.

Comment: USB flash drives normally have quite low write speeds, for USB 3.0 models it's often far below the read speeds. If you want the best speeds then consider buying an external SSD, or you can probably build one for less cheap SSD and a USB enclosure or adapter cable.

Comment: I can't believe that my USB 3.0 flash drive and my USB 2.0 flash drive have exactly the same write speed. There is a problem but I can't find out what.

Comment: What are the read speeds like and have you tried benchmarking it? If your USB controller is running in USB 2.0 mode then read speeds should obviously be affected too. According to userbenchmark.com it looks like the highest write speed figures shown are 35MB/s: http://usb.userbenchmark.com/Kingston-DataTraveler-R30-USB-30-32GB/Rating/1577.

Comment: According to userbenchmark I did now it shows that Read 92.4
Write 8.38
Mixed 11.3
31% 37.4 MB/s
4K Read 0.24
4K Write 0.003
4K Mixed 0.14
6% 0.13 MB/s

Comment: Here is a screenshot from aida64 where it shows that current speed is at usb 3.0 : http://i.imgur.com/QV2yKQL.png

Comment: Is the drive very nearly full? Have you tried formatting it and re-testing?

Comment: I formatted it in NTFS (not quick format), it took me like 15 minutes. It is empty. The read speed is pretty good for me (constant 110-115 MB/s) when I copy files from it to my SSD.

Comment: Do you have another USB 3.0 device that you can test, or are you able to test the stick on another computer that has USB 3.0? That would be the best way to determine the problem.

Comment: That's the next thing I wanna do, I will test the stick at another PC with USB 3.0, if I find any. That write speed annoys me because that is the reason I bought the PCI-E card and the stick. I will leave a comment after I test it somewhere else, hopefully I will get more answers.